# npm cache clean v/s npm cache verify

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm

What is the difference between the following:

- `npm cache clean`
- `npm cache verify`

Also what does the force option do?

It would be great if I could get an understanding specific to development on Windows platform.

Answer (score 36):

npm cache usually stored in the folder `_cacache` which is located at `C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_cacache`

> This directory is a cacache-based content-addressable cache that
>   stores all http request data as well as other package-related data.

when you run the command `npm cache verify`, you can see this path along with other details.

[image: npm cache verify]

ie; `npm cache verify`: Verifies the contents of the cache folder, garbage collecting any unneeded data, and verifying the integrity of the cache index and all cached data.

`npm cache clean --force` **delete the entire cache**. Please note, --force is a mandatory parameter, post npm v5. if you try to run `npm cache clean` without `--force` parameter, an error message will be shown.

Comment: Does the `verify` option check the cache using a freshly downloaded checksum file, or does it use a local one? If it's a local one, I would expect the `clean` option to be a safer option. Is there any scenario where the `clean` option still make sense?